# Minimizing a functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

I am doing some work on Kernel based machine learning where I encountered the following functional - $$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=0}^m(y_i-f(x_i))^2+\gamma\lVert f\rVert^2$$ Here $\gamma$ is a positive real number, $x_i,y_i$ are given (these are the training data), and norm is of the function space(Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space). Now I need to find a function that minimizes the given functional. This is what I came across - "To minimize the given functional, we take the functional derivative with respect to $f$, apply it to an element $\bar{f}$ of the function space, and set it equal to $0$. We obtain $$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=0}^m(y_i-f(x_i))^2\bar{f}(x_i)-\gamma\left<f,\bar{f}\right> = 0$$
How do we arrive at this equation, or how do we take functional derivative?

Reference - "The Mathematics of Learning:Dealing with Data, Tomaso Poggio and Steve Smale"

Comment: It is an extremely useful idea to use Google before asking questions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: I couldn't understand

Comment: @uniquesolution: Your commentary sounds a bit rude, I am sure it is unintentional. That Wikipedia page is frankly quite misleading, I don't understand what it talks about, it is surely a tool from old-fashioned calculus of variations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "functional derivative" is, in my opinion, quite old-fashioned and it can be misleading. In this context, what is meant is a **directional derivative** in the direction of $\overline f$. (This is also known as "Gateaux derivative"). The recipe is: replace any occurrence of $f$ with $f+\epsilon \overline f$ and then take a derivative at $\epsilon =0$. For the present question, 
$$\begin{split}
&\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon =0}\left( \frac1m \sum_i (y_i - f(x_i) - \epsilon \overline f(x_i))^2 +\gamma\| f+\epsilon \overline f\|^2\right)\\& =  -\frac2m\sum_i (y_i - f(x_i))\overline f (x_i) + 2\gamma \langle f|\overline f\rangle.
\end{split}$$
I have used the formula $\|f\|^2= \langle f | f \rangle $ to compute the derivative of $\| f+\epsilon \overline f\|^2$.